# richfaces contextmenu onclick not working

Tags: jsf, events, richfaces, contextmenu

I have the following:

```
<h:panelGroup id="picture">
<h:graphicImage id="pic" library="image" name="image.png" />
<rich:contextMenu event="onclick" attachTo="pic">
   <rich:menuItem value="Zoom In" id="zin">Zoom In</rich:menuItem>
</rich:contextMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Originally the event was oncontextmenu, and that works fine. But when I change it to onclick, it still responds to right click instead of left.

I already tried doing showEvent="onclick" to no avail:

```
<h:panelGroup id="picture">
<h:graphicImage id="pic" library="image" name="image.png" />
<rich:contextMenu showEvent="onclick" event="onclick" attachTo="pic">
   <rich:menuItem value="Zoom In" id="zin">Zoom In</rich:menuItem>
</rich:contextMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I am not sure which Richfaces version I'm running. But it does work with right click, not with left click as I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't know what version you're running you should find out, though it looks like you're on RF 3.3.x in which case `showEvent` won't work. Event should work though, check what event listeners are on the image.

Comment: No event listeners on the image as you can see on the code.

Comment: Well firstly I cannot see the generated code, secondly the event listeners don't show up in the code anyway, you have to inspect the element in your browser.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But I checked the code, and the img has no event listeners on it.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value of showEvent from "onclick" to "click" and it worked.